# Use Windows Briefcase from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, sync, usb-flash-drive

I have a thumb drive on which I take many of my files with me. I would like to synchronize it with my computer automatically when I connect it. I currently have a script run every time I connect it so that I can do the many things that need to be done when it connects (check for updates to the portable applications, etc.). I want my synchronization utility to:

- Detect conflicts
- work correctly when I move files or change the folder structure
- tell the difference between a file that was deleted on one side and a file that was added on the other
- work from the command line or at least have a command that will open up a window
- provide a confirmation screen before doing anything

The Windows Briefcase does all of these except the command line. Is there any program that does all of these, or is there a way to synchronize the briefcase from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most programmers know, **[Customers Don't Know What They Want. Stop Expecting Customers to Know What They Want.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000356.html)** I'm going with [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/referrals/NTE1ODgwNjA5) and [Dropbox Portable](http://forums.getdropbox.com/topic.php?id=7729), even though they don't satisfy several of the requirements I put out (no confirmation screen and no command line) because they do what I want.

Disclaimer: Dropbox link above is a referral link.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into [Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

Also check out some of the rsync-based Windows utilities such as

[Delta Copy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

It can be slightly more involved, but typically much more powerful, and is very cross-platform friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I helped design a program called [Angelia Sync](http://www.kamradtandhill.com/angeliasync.asp) which performs much of what your asking, and supports a full command line interface to access all of the features.